# CMake configuration for ffmpeg in C++ project

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, cmake

I have installed ffmpeg (version 4) with Homebrew and I am trying to use the various ffmpeg libraries in a C++ project, but I am getting multiple errors during linking.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_av_free", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_av_packet_alloc", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_av_parser_init", referenced from:
And so on ...
```

I have included the libraries as follow

```
extern "C" {
    #include <libavutil/frame.h>
    #include <libavutil/mem.h>
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
}
```

But still, this doesn't work. I think I might have missed something in my `CMakeLists.txt` file, which at the moment looks like that :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(decode_encode)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS")

add_executable(decode_encode main.cpp)
```

I most likely need to specify additional linking flags, but is there is a better way to handle the linking part in a `CMakeLists.txt` file?

Comment: You're apparently missing a suitable [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) call.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution. It appears that FFmpeg doesn't support find_package in CMake. I had to manually link the libraries as suggested [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues/1379).

Final CMakeLists.txt looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(decode_encode)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS")

find_path(AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR libavcodec/avcodec.h)
find_library(AVCODEC_LIBRARY avcodec)

find_path(AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIR libavformat/avformat.h)
find_library(AVFORMAT_LIBRARY avformat)

find_path(AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR libavutil/avutil.h)
find_library(AVUTIL_LIBRARY avutil)

find_path(AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIR libavdevice/avdevice.h)
find_library(AVDEVICE_LIBRARY avdevice)

add_executable(decode_encode main.cpp)
target_include_directories(decode_encode PRIVATE ${AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR} ${AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIR} ${AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(decode_encode PRIVATE ${AVCODEC_LIBRARY} ${AVFORMAT_LIBRARY} ${AVUTIL_LIBRARY} ${AVDEVICE_LIBRARY})
```

I am sure there is a better way to aggregate all the libraries, though.

Comment: my cmake wont find the avcodec neither other libraries. Do you have any idea of whats happening?

Comment: Probably you will need to give it a hint. By far the simplest method would be to just hardcode the path. On Linux, you could find the file's location with `find / -name avcodec.h`. On Ubuntu it seems that this is installed in  `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec/avcodec.h`

Comment: Using `pkgconfig` is a cleaner option than manually giving the path.

Answer (score 26):

PkgConfig can be used to link the libraries more conveniently, as mentioned in a comment. With CMake 3.17, this links all libav libraries:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(Foo)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(LIBAV REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET
    libavdevice
    libavfilter
    libavformat
    libavcodec
    libswresample
    libswscale
    libavutil
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PkgConfig::LIBAV
)
```

Comment: How do you export this as a dependency to consuming packages in an install?

Comment: I have a similar problem as well and I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell `CMAKE` where to find headers and libraries for `ffmpeg` in your system.
You can use the `find_package(ffmpeg` to look into your system for you and then use the CMAKE variables it defines to set up the headers for the compiler and the libraries for the linker correctly.

- header: `include_directories(${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIRS})`
- libraries: `target_link_libraries(decode_encode ${FFMPEG_LIBRARIES})`

Something like the following should serve the purpouse.

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(decode_encode)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS")


find_package(FFmpeg COMPONENTS AVCODEC AVFORMAT AVUTIL AVDEVICE REQUIRED) #add here the list of ffmpeg components required

if(FFMPEG_FOUND)
#  FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIRS  - Include directory necessary for using the required components headers.
#  FFMPEG_LIBRARIES     - Link these to use the required ffmpeg components.
#  FFMPEG_DEFINITIONS   - Compiler switches required for using the required ffmpeg components.
    message("FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIRS} ")
    message("FFMPEG_LIBRARIES = ${FFMPEG_LIBRARIES} ")
    message("FFMPEG_DEFINITIONS = ${FFMPEG_DEFINITIONS} ")

    include_directories(${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIRS})

endif()


add_executable(decode_encode main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(decode_encode ${FFMPEG_LIBRARIES})
```

**NOTE** I have not tried this, so you might need to tweak it.

Comment: Checking `XXX_FOUND` variable after `find_package(XXX REQUIRED)` is *useless*: If the package won't be found, CMake will print appropriate error log and will terminate.

Comment: Yes, but if the components are found indeed, then the message are printed. The else part is definitely useless. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help, yet I have a new issue when trying to regenerate the project `By not providing "FindFFmpeg.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "FFmpeg", but
  CMake did not find one.`

Comment: it's not work for me .Latter  I made it by `PkgConfig` and `pkg_check_modules`.