# Linking libavcodec in Cmake, find_library won't work with any library

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation

I'm trying to compile a cpp code which uses libavcodec:

```
 #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
```

I tried all variations of

```
find_package()
```

with names like `ffmpeg` for which I get

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findffmpeg.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "ffmpeg", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ffmpeg" with any
  of the following names:

    ffmpegConfig.cmake
    ffmpeg-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "ffmpeg" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "ffmpeg_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "ffmpeg"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

By the way, I did `sudo apt install -y ffmpeg` before all that.

I'm compiling with

```
add_executable(my_executable ${sources})
```

Minimal working example

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)

project(hello)

find_library(AVCODEC_LIBRARY avcodec)

add_executable(hello main.cpp)

target_link_libraries( hello PRIVATE ${AVCODEC_LIBRARY})
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
lz@vm:~/mcve$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
AVCODEC_LIBRARY
    linked by target "hello" in directory /home/lz/mcve

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/lz/mcve/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: Are you sure that `ffmpeg` comes with a CMake package definition at all? Did you try to specify the library by hand?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't think ffmpeg comes with cmake support. How should I do it by hand? I thought it wasn't possible

Comment: Using `add_libraries()` maybe?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think add_library(libavcodec) added the library but the compilation fails when it tries to load the .h of that library. Does that mean the library didn't load or that I also need to point the include path for it? I don't want to add my personal include path, I want it to be automatic

Comment: There's also need for `include_directories` I think. Read the CMake documentation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, but include_directories asks me for a specific directory. I want it to find automatically

Comment: As long there's no CMake configuration package, or you create one yourself, you can't fo that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ now I'm confused. Cmake should be easier than make. In make I simply say -lavcodec and it works. How could they miss something so easy in cmake's creation? There must be a way

Comment: _"There must be a way"_ No, unfortunately not. Their way is to define packages (doing all the low level work). If you don't have a piece of software coming with such package, CMake is only marginally easier to use than using make directly. I'd prefer to use make directly anyways, since there's less obfuscation of the build system and process, and you have more control over it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ doesn't this answer implies that there is a way? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50764569/10116440 I tried but it says that the variables are set to NOTFOUND.

Comment: Well, that answer does exactly what I told you: Do all of that stuff manually. Did you try it BTW?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I thought you were saying to me that I should specify the path location for each library, which would be exclusive for my system. Yes, I tried. I get, for each variable: CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
AVCODEC_LIBRARY

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I tried 'libxml' for example, to see if the problem was that libavcodec was not installed. But it also resulted in NOT_FOUND. Do you have a lib name I can try? Or do you know what's happening?

Comment: For CMake you omit the `lib` prefix to specify libraries, just as you do with the `-l` native compiler flags.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I also tried avcodec, xml, etc. Won't work either

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ here's my entire cmakelists.txt: https://pastebin.com/Uhj3xnrZ

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please. Links are just void.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ just updated with the example

Comment: "In make I simply say `-lavcodec` and it works." - In that case you may just place the same under `target_link_libraries` command, and it would work too. You may also omit `-l`: `target_link_libraries( hello PRIVATE libavcodec)`. Usually, if `-l` words, then `find_library` works too. Where exactly `avcodec` is located on your PC? (You may examine files list of `ffmpeg` package for find that location).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what was missing (even though `libavcodec` appeared in some folders of my system)

```
sudo apt install -y libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavdevice-dev libavfilter-dev
```