# Cmake error with ffmpeg and PkgConfig: cannot find -lpkgcfg_lib_LIBAV_stdc++

Tags: c++, linux, ffmpeg, cmake

I want to create my C++ project using ffmpeg and cmake on Ubuntu 18.04, but comes up with errors:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for modules 'libavdevice;libavfilter;libavformat;libavcodec;libswresample;libswscale;libavutil'
--   Found libavdevice, version 59.0.100
--   Found libavfilter, version 8.1.103
--   Found libavformat, version 59.4.101
--   Found libavcodec, version 59.4.101
--   Found libswresample, version 4.0.100
--   Found libswscale, version 6.0.100
--   Found libavutil, version 57.3.100
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/yg/Documents/xsplay/build
Scanning dependencies of target xsplay
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xsplay.dir/src/ffplay.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable xsplay
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpkgcfg_lib_LIBAV_stdc++-NOTFOUND
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpkgcfg_lib_LIBAV_gcc_s-NOTFOUND
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpkgcfg_lib_LIBAV_gcc-NOTFOUND
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/xsplay.dir/build.make:233: recipe for target 'xsplay' failed
make[2]: *** [xsplay] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/xsplay.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/xsplay.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

FFmpeg version is 4.4, built from source code.

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --extra-libs="-lpthread" \
  --cxx="g++" \
  --ld="g++" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
  --disable-ffplay \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-gnutls \
  --enable-libaom \
  --enable-libass \
  --enable-libfdk-aac \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libopus \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-libx265 \
  --enable-nonfree && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make && \
make install && \
hash -r
```

I removed unnecessary code to simplify the project, below is main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern "C"
{
#include <libavutil/frame.h>
#include <libavutil/mem.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("xsplay\n");
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt is modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61427931/8609327, I only changed cmake version to 3.10.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(xsplay)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(LIBAV REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET
    libavdevice
    libavfilter
    libavformat
    libavcodec
    libswresample
    libswscale
    libavutil
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PkgConfig::LIBAV
)
```

Please help me solve the problem, thanks!

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760024/cmake-configuration-for-ffmpeg-in-c-project/50764569#50764569 → " It appears that FFmpeg doesn't support find_package in CMake "

Comment: @KnudLarsen: The referenced answer uses pkg-config approach, it uses `find_package`  for `PkgConfig` module, not for FFmpeg itself.

Comment: @KnudLarsen: Thanks, this answer could solve my problem.But I still wonder what caused my problem when using `PkgConfig`.